# JSF links not working on Facelets

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, facelets

I have created a JSF 2 page which uses Facelets to define the structure of the page.

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="content">
        <ui:insert name="content">

        </ui:insert>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <ui:include src="footer.xhtml" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This is footer.xhtml

```
<h:commandButton value="Link Page 1"  action="page1.xhtml" />     
<h:commandButton value="Link Page 2" action="page2.xhtml" />
```

As you can see, in the footer.xhtml I have some buttons which I use to move between pages.

Unfortunately navigation does not work when buttons are placed into the footer.xhtml page. On the other hand if they are placed in the main div (content) they work correctly.

Is there a way to let them work in the footer too ?

P.s. My environment Java 1.6 on JBoss application server 7
Thanks
Linda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your commandButton/commandLink elements wont' work if you don't put them into a form element `<h:form></h:form>`. 
Remember to add the proper namespace to your `<ui:composition>` element '`xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html`'

Comment: Thanks. Shame on me! I've forgot to include it in a form. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For pure navigation you should use `h:button` instead of `h:commandButton`. The latter indeed needs a surrounding form as stated by Kris.

If you change your buttons as follows, they should work regardless where you place them on the page:

```
<h:button value="Link Page 1" outcome="page1" />
<h:button value="Link Page 2" outcome="page2" />
```

The `.xhtml` suffix is appended by JSF.

Comment: Indeed, using POST for pure page-to-page navigation is Bad™. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink